# How do I get 'hosted' from 'He had a party at his house'?

Tags: nlp, semantics

I'm new to NLP so bear with me if this isn't possible yet. I am interested in taking a sentence like 'He had a party at his house' to 'He hosted a party at his house' or simply the verb 'hosted'. Is this possible with current NLP technology or does this require deep semantic analysis that isn't currently available since it involves converting a nondescript verb into a descriptive one based on the receiving object?

Comment: Have you looked at Framenet? _Party_ is part of a frame that involves at least a host, a guest, a location, and some activities. All of which can be referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the approach of [Sag et al (2001)](http://lingo.stanford.edu/pubs/WP-2001-03.pdf) on multi-word expressions, specifically the parts about light-verb constructions, which they model computationally with an HPSG-based grammar. See references in that paper for background, and also [Copestake & Flickinger (2000)](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~aac10/papers/lrec2000.pdf).